# DC motor rpm slower than the rated rpm

Tags: motor, dc, shunt

A seperately excited shunt dc motor of 336 KW with rated rpm from 500-700, when it is operated on 420 rpm what will be the effect of current on it?

Comment: How are you slowing the motor down?

Comment: By lowering the voltage of armature keeping the current constant of field

Comment: Actually the load current reaches upto 1kA, that is a large amount that can effect the life of the motor, if i replace it with 596 KW motor with same 420 rpm will it be suitable?

Comment: Please revise the question to include all relevant information. Don't dole it out a little at a time in the comments.

Comment: What is the rated armature voltage and current?

Comment: armature rated voltage is 460 V and Amps 780 and rated rpm are 500/700

Comment: If the rated RPM is 500/700, why is 850-1200 stated in the question? Rated RPM is usually the RPM at which rated torque and power can be provided continuously. I interpret the lower RPM to be the lowest RPM at which the motor can provide rated torque continuously. The motor provides less than rated power at speeds below rated speed. I am voting to close this question as unclear until it is revised to include all the relevant information. Does the motor have a rating plate. If so, all of the information marked should be part of the question.

Comment: I see that you may be referring to ratings for the existing and replacement motors. 500/700 and 850-1200 may be RPM ratings for full / reduced field.

Comment: sorry i have edited my question

Comment: If the proposed replacement motor is rated 596 kW at 500 RPM, I would expect it to be adequate based on the 336 kW motor operating at 1000 amps at 420 RPM with the same rated voltage and speed. A good question would have the complete  existing motor data, the operating data and the proposed motor data all clearly stated in the question rather than in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the armature voltage is lowered with the field held constant the current will be proportional to load torque. If the load requires the same torque at the lower speed, the current will not change. If the load requires less torque at the lower speed, the torque will be less. If the motor is self cooled, the temperature will increase. That will also have some influence on the speed and current at the lower voltage.

There is no general rule defining the lowest speed that the motor can operate with no danger to the motor. The motor should have a maximum insulation temperature rating marked on the rating plate. Operation above that temperature will shorten the life of the motor. Unless the motor is cooled by a separately powered blower, it depends on the speed of the rotor to cool itself. Heat dissipated in the motor is mostly determined by armature current. Armature current is mostly determined by load torque.

Motor manufacturers can provide speed vs. torque curves, curling curves and other information that can be used to predict the insulation temperature under various operating conditions. Without additional information from the manufacturer, it is very difficult to predict what operation is safe for the motor.

Comment: what should be the percentage of rpm on which the motor should run lesser than the rated rpm so that there is not any danger to the motor?

Comment: for example 40% less or 50% etc

Comment: See revised answer.